# Assign materials color based on rotation and scale of object using nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I am using blender 4.0 and trying to assign the color of material based on the rotation and scale of the object, that is what the three "values" are for. However, this is not easily transferable to other objects, unless I manually change the object the values are referring to. I am wondering, is there a way to use the object rotation and scale as an input without having to manually specify the object that the material is assigned to? Thanks [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use named atributes in geometry nodes so the values are independant to each object every time you add the node modifier to an object

[image]

You will then be able to use them in the shader editor as an input

[image]